# Couldn't find ROS executables, Arduino

Tags: arduino, ros

I am trying to run this code:

```
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py_port:=/dev/ttyACM0_baud:=115200
```

and I keep getting this error :

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named /opt/ros/melodic/share/rosserial_python/serial_node.py_port:=/dev/ttyACM0_baud:=115200
```

I'm lost and have no idea what to do. do i have to make it executable?
I did source devel/setup.bash and nothing.

I am trying to follow this:
https://github.com/ASME-ground-robot/2021-22/blob/main/README.md#operating-the-robotic-arm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a space before the parameter you're trying to set. Notice that the error message is looking for a python file that *includes* the parameter name. Instead you want

```
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py _port:=/dev/ttyACM0_baud:=115200
```